# Rails RSpec, DRY specs: shared example vs. helper method vs. custom matcher

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I have the following test repeated once for each HTTP method/controller action combination within a controller spec:

```
it "requires authentication" do
  get :show, id: project.id
  # Unauthenticated users should be redirected to the login page
  expect(response).to redirect_to new_user_session_path
end
```

I've found the three following ways to refactor it and eliminate repetition. Which one is the most appropriate?

#### Shared Example

It seems to me that shared examples are the most appropriate solution. However, having to use a block in order to pass the `params` to the shared example feels a bit awkward.

```
shared_examples "requires authentication" do |http_method, action|
  it "requires authentication" do
    process(action, http_method.to_s, params)
    expect(response).to redirect_to new_user_session_path
  end
end

RSpec.describe ProjectsController, type: :controller do
  describe "GET show", :focus do
    let(:project) { Project.create(name: "Project Rigpa") }

    include_examples "requires authentication", :GET, :show do
      let(:params) { {id: project.id} }
    end
  end
end
```

#### Helper Method

This has the advantage of not requiring a block to pass `project.id` to the helper method.

```
RSpec.describe ProjectsController, type: :controller do
  def require_authentication(http_method, action, params)
    process(action, http_method.to_s, params)
    expect(response).to redirect_to new_user_session_path
  end

  describe "GET show", :focus do
    let(:project) { Project.create(name: "Project Rigpa") }

    it "requires authentication" do
      require_authentication(:GET, :show, id: project.id )
    end
  end
end
```

#### Custom Matcher

It would be nice to have a single-line test.

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :require_authentication do |http_method, action, params|
  match do
    process(action, http_method.to_s, params)
    expect(response).to redirect_to Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.new_user_session_path
  end
end

RSpec.describe ProjectsController, type: :controller do
  describe "GET show", :focus do
    let(:project) { Project.create(name: "Project Rigpa") }

    it { is_expected.to require_authentication(:GET, :show, {id: project.id}) }
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe you can move the helper method to /support/helpers and leverage them in your other controllers with an include. The custom matcher is probably the rspec way but who cares if it works for you

Comment: I like to take gradual approach, so probably using helper method first and when I see it useful elsewhere, then refactor it into a custom matcher

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A suggestion provided by didroe in [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/ruby/comments/6ifvx5/rails_rspec_dry_specs_shared_example_vs_helper/) got me thinking that placing the method/action call (`process`) within shared code is not a good idea as it increases complexity (reduces readability) and does not actually reduce code duplication.

After searching some more, I have found what I believe to be best option in the [Everyday Rails Testing with RSpec by Aaron Sumner](https://leanpub.com/everydayrailsrspec) book (p. 102).

Create the following custom matcher:

```
# spec/support/matchers/require_login.rb
RSpec::Matchers.define :require_login do |expected|
  match do |actual|
    expect(actual).to redirect_to \
      Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.new_user_session_path
  end

  failure_message do |actual|
    "expected to require login to access the method"
  end

  failure_message_when_negated do |actual|
    "expected not to require login to access the method"
  end

  description do
    "redirect to the login form"
  end
end
```

And use a test like the following for each action of each controller:

```
it "requires authentication" do
  get :show, id: project.id
  expect(response).to require_login
end
```

Compared to repeating `expect(response).to redirect_to new_user_session_path` in all tests, this approach has the following advantages:

- Improved maintanability. If we eventually have to change this assertion, we change it in one place instead of having to change dozens or hundreds of tests.
- Better failure messages.

What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

In the case you describe, I would go for **RSpec Custom Matchers**. They keep your specs easier to read and closer to the domain of you application.
https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-4/docs/custom-matchers/define-matcher

I would use shared_examples to specify more complex scenarios and call it_behaves_like to check it all at once in different contexts.

You should try to avoid helper methods if possible and only use them in a single file if it helps keep your specs clean.